# Keep the position of an absolute element by reducing the window

Tags: html, css

I need help, I have a box that takes up the entire window. This box is responsive as you can see with the red border.

In this box, I want to add tables that have a defined X and Y position.

My problem is that if I reduce the window, at a certain point the tables come out of the box.

So I'd like to be able to keep the same positions but have them adapt if the window size changes.

EDIT : Here is a small sketch to visualise what I would like to do:

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sDo9.png)

Here is my code :

```css
.box {
  border: 5px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  resize: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
        <div class="content" style="left:700px; top:220px; z-index: 0;">
            <table>
                
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">TITLE</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>FUNCT1</td>
                        <td>John Doe</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>FUNCT2</td>
                        <td>John Doe</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>FUNCT3</td>
                        <td>John Doe</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

Can you please help me, have a nice day !

Comment: If you want responsiveness don't use fixed widths.

Answer (score 1):

try this snippet

```
.box {
position: absolute
height: 100%;
width: 100%;  
}
.content{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center; 
}
```

remove your inline styling `left:700px; top:220px;` since it is always forcing the position. should give you a more desired result you will still need to fine tune to your needs